# Importing Vue Router Types in TypeScript - Missing Exported Members Issue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a Vue 3 project with TypeScript and Vue Router, and I'm encountering issues with importing types from the vue-router package. I've followed the recommended import syntax for Vue Router 4, but I keep getting errors related to missing exported members. I've checked my package.json and tsconfig.json files, and they seem to be set up correctly.

Here's the relevant part of my **package.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    // ...
  }
}
```

And my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Here's the import statement I'm using in my **router/index.ts** file:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteLocationNormalized, NavigationGuardNext, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
```

However, I'm consistently getting errors like:

> Module 'vue-router' has no exported member 'RouteLocationNormalized'.
> Did you mean to use 'import RouteLocationNormalized from "vue-router"'
> instead?

To troubleshoot, I've attempted various solutions, including:

Dependency Reinstallation: I deleted my node_modules directory and package-lock.json file, then ran npm install to ensure my dependencies were fresh.

TypeScript Compatibility: I confirmed that the TypeScript version specified in my package.json (4.5.5) is compatible with Vue Router 4.

IDE/Editor Check: I made sure my IDE (or code editor) was up to date and correctly recognizing TypeScript typings.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Has anyone else encountered similar issues with Vue Router 4 and TypeScript, or is there something specific I might be overlooking?

Comment: `RouteLocationNormalized` is exported as a type, so to import you should use `import type` as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names)

Comment: Can you check that you have this file in your node_modules? `node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.d.ts` and within it, search for `RouteLocationNormalized`. If it exists, the issue isn't with the dependency but with a Typescript / VSCode configuration